# How to indent comments start and end to be on the same column?

Tags: vim, formatting, indentation

I am editing a C code, I need to place the start of the comment in same column and end of comments in some different column on all the lines..

e.g.

```
int i;         /* some var */
int j;         /* some other */
char c;   /* new char */
```

output required is

```
int i;         /* some var    */
int j;         /* some other  */
char c;        /* new char    */
```

I tried `indent`, read man page but didn't find a option that i could use (too many flag, maybe i missed something).
I also tried a vim-plugin `Tabularize` but not getting how to achieve the above.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

With `Tabularize`, you could split each line by both `/*` and `*/` in 3 sections with this command:

First select the lines you want to format, then type:

```
Tabularize /\(\/\*\|\*\/\)
```

This is basically equal to the regular expression `(/\*|\*/)` in other languages, but Vim requires additional escapes.

Result:

```
int i;  /* some var   */
int j;  /* some other */
char c; /* new char   */
```

To produce the exact result from your example, you can tell Tabularize to add extra spaces like this:

```
Tabularize /\(\/\*\|\*\/\)/l8l1l2
```